# Blender Wacom buttons not recognized - Linux Mint

Tags: interface, linux

I am having issue with Blender not catching Wacom buttons when pressed. Gimp and Houdini and every other app are working perfectly.
I set buttons using *xsetwacom set* command. Is there anything specific I need to do to enable this?

Thanks!